# What is wrong with this following c# code just trying to find out Length and reverse of a given String

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am just trying to find out the reverse and length of a string. Here is the snippet of the Code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your String: ");
        string InputString = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] String_Array = InputString.ToCharArray();
        int Length = 0;

        foreach (char c in String_Array)
        {
            Length++;
        }
        char[] String_Reverse = null;
        for (int i = Length - 1, j = 0; Length >= 0; Length--, j++)
        {
            //Here is the error I am facing, Null Reference Exception

            String_Reverse[j] = String_Array[i];
        }
        string Reverse = new string(String_Reverse);

        Console.WriteLine("Length of the String " + InputString + " is :" + Length + " and Reverse of the String is :" + Reverse);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: also the char array or even string has Length property. no need to use foreach and count.

Comment: thats alright, But i just want to know what is wrong in this code.

Comment: you set null to String_Reverse. you need to create new array. `char[] String_Reverse = new char[Length]`

Comment: "//Here is the error I am facing" -- You must **always** post **which error** you're facing. Not just "here it happens". **What** happened?

Answer (score 1):

You never actually initialize `String_Reverse` as an array

Also, instead of using a `foreach` loop to get the length of an array you can use `String_Array.Length` this will return the length of the array without having to loop over each item in the array.